# Google Search Tips For French Words on Images

Tags: google-image-search, keyword, search-operators

I like to find film posters or book covers featuring a word that I am learning. Sometimes it is difficult to find anything using Google Image search, so I need to improve my search terms.

For example, I'm trying to find an example of the word `ennuyeux`, used in a film poster or a book title. Usually, I search for `ennuyeux affiche` or `ennuyeux livre`, but this does not always work.

I tried `livre avec le mot «ennuyeux» dans le titre` with the intended meaning *book with the word "ennuyeux" in the title*, but this is not producing better search results.

Does anyone have any ideas on improving my Google Image search?

Answer (score 1):

You really would have more luck using a more specialized website that you can search for *titles*, like Amazon.fr or IMDB to get examples of that. You're going to find FAR too many examples of books and movies being called boring for any Google search to be useful at all.

In any case, "Ennuyeux" strikes me as a word that is REALLY unlikely to find it's way into a title. I couldn't find it used on Amazon, IMDB, Librarything, Noosfere, Bibliopoche, Bédéthèque.... Even Worldcat gave only a few tiny, ridiculously obscure results.